# Install MongoDB C# driver for SSIS

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2012, ssis, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to build some ETL package using SSIS to load data between MongoDB and MSSQL Server. According to this article [Importing MongoDB Data Using SSIS 2012](http://arcanecode.com/2014/01/14/importing-mongodb-data-using-ssis-2012/), I need to install MongoDB C# driver. I downloaded [CSharpDriver-2.2.3.zip](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases/download/v2.2.3/CSharpDriver-2.2.3.zip). However, gacutil complains the DLL is not signed with strong names. I then went to download the [whole solution of the driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/archive/v2.2.3.zip) and hoping to compile and sign it myself. Surprisingly, my Visual Studio 2012 can't even recognize lambda expression in the code and throw a lot errors. I can see the projects in the solution are using .NET Framework 4.5

I haven't done much C# programming since .NET Framework 2.0, so not quite familiar with all the recent stuff. My ultimate goal is to enable the MongoDB driver for SSIS. I would appreciate if someone could either:

- Help me with compilation of the driver
- Or point me to a copy of strongly signed driver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to download community edition? it's free. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Comment: Salem, I'm using Professional edition. Is that not supposed to be more "powerful"? Anyway, I'll try the community edition. Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned visual studio 2012, which is old and doesn't support most of modern C#. I'm suggesting 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You can add c#6 support to the project by installing the nuget package

Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers

You'll still get the red lines all over the place but you should be able to compile after that....

Hope that helps...

Aj